# UITextView custom action for tap on number

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in my app which is used to display some string with numbers. These numbers can be phone numbers or other numbers specific to the app. If user taps the phone number they should be asked if they want to make a call (This is done by default). However, if the user taps on the other number which is not a phone number but is specific to the app, the action should be custom e.g. it should call a method in the view controller with the number as an argument.

I had a quick search but couldn't find any easy solution.

Any idea how this could be done? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by implementing 'UITextViewDelegate'.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange

{
    DLog(@"URL is %@", URL.absoluteString)

    NSString *host = [URL host];
    NSNumber *adIdInLink = nil;

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 3);
    NSString *subString = [URL.absoluteString substringWithRange:range];

    if ([subString isEqualToString:@"tel"] && !host) {
        // this is a number - do whatever you want
        NSString *stringWithAdId = [URL.absoluteString substringFromIndex:4];
        if ([HJUtilities isValidAdId:stringWithAdId]) {
            // this is the ad Id a custom number used in my app
            adIdInLink = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[stringWithAdId integerValue]];
        }
        else {
            // this was a phone number - let the default behaviour
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UITextView with its delegate set to the parent UIViewController:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                             action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [myTextView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

The add a handler method to your UIViewController:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
      UITextView *textView = (UITextView*)sender;
      NSString *number = textView.text;

}
```

eta: You need to add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate as a protocol to your UIViewController too:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

---

update:

How about using the [UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChangeSelection%3a) method textViewDidChangeSelection instead?

Inspect the selectedRange property of the textview to check its contents.

Comment: This won't work. First the method should only be called when tap on the number (not on the whole textView). 2nd the text in textView is not only that number but it also have other strings and the numbers are highlighted using the default detection. Thanks!

Comment: .-., really you want pixel detection on only the number not the view that holds the number?

Comment: @JohnRiselvato no, I don't need pixel detection. The numbers are highlighted in the textView. I just want to override the default behaviour of tapping on the numbers. By default it asks to initiate a call to that number.

Comment: @Will and John.. plz see my answer. Sorry for posting so late. I had solved the problem long ago. Cheers!